# Getting and extra size on my page

Tags: html, css

as you can see in this links

http://hybrid-tech.net/clients/ferrara/onepagemodel1/

and the end of the page I getting a white line and I don't understand why.

Could you help me to resolve this issues.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding-bottom` line in `body` of the CSS; that makes that "white line" appear.

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
}
```

to

```
body {
    color: #5a5a5a;
}
```